# Psensor warning - What does it mean?

Tags: cpu, fan, overheating, psensor

I installed Psensor because I have had a new comp with problems, it sometimes freezes up on me. This might be caused by heat but it could be another cause.

After implementing all sensors, Psensor displays a warning, the temp icon in my dock is red. It also warns me my mobo is getting up to 30c, but that doesn't seem very high to me.

I have an identical computer which does not have any problems, and I installed Psensor on it, and no warning at all but the temp is the same...so I am really wondering why the warning. Could it be a fan? The good one says a fan is running, the bad one says no fan, and while the fan in the bad one spins, it could be the source of the problem.

I looked around a bit but couldn't find any info on how to get this info. Could anyone shed some light on this for me? I have been battling for awhile and am pretty mixed up by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Psensor, by default, the high threshold of the alarm is set to 60C (and not 30C as you reported) for all sensors.

Obviously, 60C is not too much hot for most hardware components. You can set the threshold according to the specifications of your component to better match your needs.

By default, low threshold for fan is 0, if you have enabled warnings for fan and one is stopped or not wired, it will raise a warning.

When a warning is raised, you also have a bubble notification at the top right of the screen once allowing you to know the name of the component which is raising the alarm. Maybe you have enabled warning for a fan which is stopped or not wired?

Comment: Yes it seems the fan is somewhat faulty, it runs but doesn't register with the sensors for some reason, its not running right because its set to full on but is adjusting speed from time to time. It registers a warning upon startup for the SYSTIN.

Comment: Thanks, by the way, for this excellent tool. Its been very useful.